confusion due to the difference of "terms" between FOL and SMT-LIB
In first-order logic (FOL), terms evaluate to values other than truth values, i.e., values of terms are neither true nor false.

Reference: Chap. 2.1 from The Calculus of Computation

By constrast, in SMT-LIB that is the standard input format of SMT solvers, terms can evaluate to truth values, because formulas are boolean-typed terms.

Reference: https://smt-lib.org/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf (in p. 27, "Formulas in SMT- LIB are just well-sorted terms of sort Bool.")

I have the following question due to this difference in "terms".
[Question] Why do we restrict terms in FOL so that they evaluate to non-truth values? Why not just allow terms to evaluate to truth values as in SMT-LIB?

@D.W. I reduced to one question.

Can you give an example of a term that evaluates to a value other than true or false, to make it more concrete?  Why do you think that terms in SMT solvers always evaluate to either true or false?

First-order logic is what it is.  It has a particular definition and that's what it is.  There is no artificial restriction.
To ask "why" something is a certain way, you have to imagine some other reasonable alternative, but it's not clear what alternative you have in mind.  In any case, if you try to imagine some variant of logic that has other properties, it's not first-order logic anymore; it is something more complicated.
I am not entirely sure that it makes sense to talk about terms in FOL as "evaluating" to something.  In the language I'm used to, to talk about what a term evaluates to, we typically need an assignment that maps all free variables to true or false. Lacking that, I'm not sure that the notion of "evaluating to" is defined.
SMT solvers accept inputs that can contain terms that don't necessarily evaluate to true or false.  For instance $\exists x,y . x \lor y$ is true (so it could be said to evaluate to either true or false), but $x \lor y$ can't be said to evaluate to either true or false, as $x,y$ are free variables.
